# Convert a string array to a array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say the string is like `a = "['Hello', 'World']"`. After the conversion, `a = ['Hello', 'World']` and the type is a list.

Comment: You could use ast.literal_eval

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()`?

Comment: Replace the ' with " and load it as json?

Answer (score -1):

It's called expression evaluation. Read about Python's [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) and [literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Notice that it may be dangerous, so read the docs carefully.

Comment: Eval is really bad advice and very dangerous.